# Detect checkbox toggle change in telerik RadGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have a checkbox column in radgridview, what do I want ? when checkbox is true then label1 turns red, when false label1 turns black.

this code snippet runs fine only when the checkbox column evaluates to true, whereas when false label1 shows no color change.

```
private void C_0_GridData_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (C_0_GridData.ActiveEditor is RadCheckBoxEditor)
    {
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else { label1.ForeColor = Color.Black; }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: If you step through your code in the debugger, you will see that there is no check for the `Checkbox` value, only for the ActiveEditor type. You need to check for the Checked value of the Checkbox and then act - Red for true, else Black

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. It is unknown what you mean by… _”this code snippet runs fine only when the checkbox column evaluates to true,”_ … ? … What do you mean by this? Check box “COLUMNS” do not evaluate to `true` or `false.` If all check boxes are `true` or all check boxes are `false` then I guess you could say the check box “column” is all `true` or all `false.` But if the multiple rows of check boxes are different then, what would the “column” evaluate to? Am I missing something here?

Comment: In addition, it is unclear what you mean when you state that… _”when checkbox is true then label1 turns red, when false label1 turns black.”_ … ? …Which “checkbox” are you referring to? A column of check boxes has many check boxes… and you could certainly change the label color if one check box is changed, but then the labels color would only be determined by which check box was LAST changed. In other words, given this context, the labels color becomes meaningless. Again, sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnG sorry, I will try to explain briefly with a simple example, because if I explain in full it will make too many posts that I write.. I mean, how can I find out the condition of the checkbox column, if it is checked then label1 turns red, if not in tick label1 goes black, let's say I have only one row of data with checkbox column in radgridview located in column 1.

Comment: @JayV that's why I'm asking.. I got the code from the telerik group, but no further answer yet.. the code only works when the radgriview column is checked, then label1 changes color to red, but, when I uncheck it, label1 doesn't change color to black.. if any solution can you help me? Sorry, I'm still in the learning stage.

Comment: I am guessing since this is a Telerik grid… that the check box column has a header that will allow you to check or un-check all the cells… if this is the case then I am betting you want to subscribe to the grids [HeaderCellToggleStateChanged](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewcheckboxcolumn) event.

Comment: @JohnG nice to meet john, yes my code follows the way you indicated, i.e. via ValueChanged event. now, how to know if GridViewCheckBoxColumn is checked or not ? let's say if it is checked show message "true", otherwise show "false" message via messagebox..

Comment: @JohnG if using built-in gridview, this problem is actually solved, but I don't know how to telerik gridview.

Comment: The grids `ValueChanged` event and the `HeaderCellToggleStateChanged` are two different events. The event I pointed to is the event the fires when the “header” cell check box is changed. I am guessing the event you are using is referring to a cell IN the grid and not necessarily the “header” cell.

Comment: @JohnG You are absolutely right.. can you help me achieve what I want?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you need help with. If there is more to this question… then, either [edit] this question or start a new one if it is a different question. In your current question it appears the problem is that you are using the wrong event to color the label.

Answer (score 0):

finally, to detect whether checkboxcolumn in radgridview is in checked position or not, this simple code works as I expected:

```
private void C_0_GridData_CellValueChanged(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bool completed = Convert.ToBoolean(C_0_GridData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        if (completed == true)
        { label1.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
        else
        { label1.ForeColor = Color.Black; }
    }
```

I put this code inside the CellValueChanged event, instead of using the ValueChanged event.

Comment: I have a question… if the label changes to red when the user “checks” some cell’s check box and there are other check box cells in the same column that also have been checked… then how are you going to know “which” check box changed the label to red? And the corollary… if the label changes to black when the user un-checks a cell and there are other un-checked cells in the column… then how would you know “which” un-checked check box colored the label? Coloring the label appears awkward in this context and I do not see what the red or black colors would signify.

Comment: @JohnG hi John, sorry to confuse.. the crux of this problem is I want to know the condition of CheckboxColumn, for example label1 is black paper. if the small box is checked the black paper turns red, and vice versa. i just want to create a trigger using that checkbox state to run the next few lines of command, no matter what checkbox is on any line, what matters is if any of the little boxes contained in that line is checked it will trigger a color change in on black paper to red.

Comment: @JohnG But I'm still in the learning stage, maybe my mistakes can be understood .. and your answer is a good input for me. thanks john..

Comment: It is not important, if it works for you then go for it. I am just not understanding what the labels color signifies? Your last comment states that… _”what matters is if any of the little boxes contained in that line is checked it will trigger a color change in on black paper to red.”_ … ? … So, if you walked up to this form and saw that the label was red… then what would you conclude from that? In other words, if by simply looking at the color of the label… what can you say/conclude about the “check state of the column”?